# Cookie not stored on response/redirect

Tags: redirect, cookies

I simply cannot make a 302 redirect send a cookie.

I have a 302 request at `https://mysite-api.azurewebsites.net/api/123456` which responds with:

```
     {
        status: 302,
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
          "Set-Cookie": `testcookie3=abcd; Max-Age=2592000; SameSite=Lax; Secure; Path=/;`,
          Location: `www.mysite.com`,
        },
        body: "Redirecting..."
      }
```

I'm calling it with from my local machine, just as a html file in chrome/firefox:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form
      action="https://mysite-api.azurewebsites.net/api/123456/redirect"
      method="post"
    >
      <label for="token">Token:</label>
      <input type="text" id="token" name="token" /><br /><br />
      <button type="submit">Submit this tab</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can see it call the `redirect` request, I can see the reponse cookie is set.

However, it's not stored, and on the actual redirect it's immediately removed.

The test page simply displays `Cookie: |{document.cookie}|` and it's blank, no cookies are received by the redirect site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when doing a redirect you simply **must** have the UI and API on the same domain.

Since this was the case in production, I had to ensure my development environment is also hosted on the same domain, and then the cookie:

```
Token=ABCDE; Max-Age=2592000; Path=/; Domain=subdomain.mysite.dev; HttpOnly; Secure;
```

Worked, for the UI at `subdomain.mysite.dev` and api at `api.subdomain.mysite.dev`.